# calling a 2nd method is not working - asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

```
public static int MassEmpNumUpdate(string empToUpdateFrom, string empToUpdateTo)
{
    string sql;
    int retval;
    using (cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString()))
    {
        cn.Open();
        sql = "uspUpdateDet"; // THIS IS THE 1ST SP
        using (cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpToUpdateFrom", empToUpdateFrom);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpToUpdateTo", empToUpdateTo);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            retval = (int)cmd.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value;

        }

        if (retval == 0)
        {
            sql = "uspUpdatePrev"; // THIS IS THE 2ND SP - not working :(
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpToUpdateFrom", empToUpdateFrom);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpToUpdateTo", empToUpdateTo);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@returnvalue", SqlDbType.Int).Direction =   ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        return retval;
    }

}
```

}

I have 2 stored procedure (that will update 2 tables) the uspUpdateDet and uspUpdatePrev.
My question is why is my second (uspUpdatePrev) statement is not working.  btw the sp is working right from sql server 08.

SP1:

set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspUpdateDet]

```
 @EmpToUpdateFrom varchar(7)
, @EmpToUpdateTo varchar(7)
```

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @affectedRows int
SET @affectedRows = 0;

BEGIN
    UPDATE  tbl1
    SET DET1 = @EmpToUpdateTo
    WHERE DET1 = @EmpToUpdateFrom
    SET @affectedRows = @affectedRows + @@ROWCOUNT
END

BEGIN
    UPDATE  tbl1
    SET DET2 = @EmpToUpdateTo
    WHERE DET2 = @EmpToUpdateFrom
    SET @affectedRows = @affectedRows + @@ROWCOUNT
END

BEGIN
    UPDATE  tbl1
    SET L1 = @EmpToUpdateTo
    WHERE L2 = @EmpToUpdateFrom
    SET @affectedRows = @affectedRows + @@ROWCOUNT
END

BEGIN
    UPDATE  tbl1
    SET L2 = @EmpToUpdateTo
    WHERE L2 = @EmpToUpdateFrom
    SET @affectedRows = @affectedRows + @@ROWCOUNT
END

BEGIN
    UPDATE  tbl1
    SET L3 = @EmpToUpdateTo
    WHERE L3 = @EmpToUpdateFrom
    SET @affectedRows = @affectedRows + @@ROWCOUNT
END

BEGIN
    UPDATE  tbl1
    SET L4 = @EmpToUpdateTo
    WHERE L4 = @EmpToUpdateFrom
    SET @affectedRows = @affectedRows + @@ROWCOUNT
END

BEGIN
    UPDATE  tbl1
    SET L5 = @EmpToUpdateTo
    WHERE L5 = @EmpToUpdateFrom
    SET @affectedRows = @affectedRows + @@ROWCOUNT
END

BEGIN
    UPDATE  tbl1
    SET L6 = @EmpToUpdateTo
    WHERE L6 = @EmpToUpdateFrom
    SET @affectedRows = @affectedRows + @@ROWCOUNT
END

BEGIN
    UPDATE  tbl1
    SET L7 = @EmpToUpdateTo
    WHERE L7 = @EmpToUpdateFrom
    SET @affectedRows = @affectedRows + @@ROWCOUNT
END

BEGIN
    UPDATE  tbl1
    SET L8 = @EmpToUpdateTo
    WHERE L8 = @EmpToUpdateFrom
    SET @affectedRows = @affectedRows + @@ROWCOUNT
END

return @affectedRows

Comment: Is it possible that (retalValue != 0) ? Can you post the code of your 1st SP?

Comment: You are asking why something is not working without explaining what are the expected results (what is the SP supposed to do, ...) and what are the actual results (exception stack trace, wrong data, ...). You could be a little more specific.

Comment: Are you sure that the return value from the first stored is being set that way?  Looking at MSDN's documentation, you may want to set retval equal to the result of that ExecuteNonQuery rather than try to get it from the Parameters collection.

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message you receive when stepping into the execution of the 2nd stored proc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First guess is that your using statement in the first block is closing your connection. What error are you getting?

Edit: After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016800/does-closing-a-database-connection-in-dispose-method-is-right) it seems like this does not happen so the best guess would be that you're not hitting the block at all. Are you sure that's happening?

Comment: I am not getting an error is just a message:  no records were updated, but there are some records exist.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you mean by "not working", but most likely `retval` is not `0`.

You really ought to debug the application and see what you are getting back from the first call.